# Encoding html entities in url string

Tags: php

I'm trying to prepare a url that has special characters in it, to be used as GET variables in a php file. I think I need html entities and urlencode, which I then need to decode in the other php file. But I'm running into some problems with correctly encoding them. 
This is what I have:

```
<?php $title = "This is a ‘simple’ test"; ?>
<?php $titleent = htmlentities($title); ?>
<?php $titleentencoded = urlencode($titleent); ?>
<?php $date = '21-12-2011'; ?>

    <p>Title: <?php echo $title; ?></p>
    <p>Title html entities: <?php echo $titleent; ?></p>
    <p>Title encoded: <?php echo $titleencoded; ?></p>

    <p><a href="index.php?title=<?php echo $titleencoded; ?>&date=<?php echo $date; ?>">Go!</a></p>
```

The $titleencoded variable turns out to be empty. I'm overlooking something obvious but I can't see it. What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT:** New code after suggestions

Okay, so here's what I came up with:

```
<?php $title = "This is a ‘simple’ test"; ?>
<?php $titleentencoded = urlencode($title); ?>
<?php $htmlent = htmlentities($titleentencoded); ?> 
<?php $date = '21-12-2011'; ?>

<p>Title: <?php echo $title; ?></p>
<p>Title encoded: <?php echo $titleentencoded; ?></p>
<p>Title html entities: <?php echo $htmlent; ?></p>

<p><a href="index.php?title=<?php echo $htmlent; ?>&date=<?php echo $date; ?>">Go!</a></p>
```

Is this the right way?

Comment: Don't use `htmlentities()`. Use `htmlspecialchars()` instead. What you're using will convert ALL characters to HTML entities (which is NOT what you want).

Comment: Please see the edit to the original code. Is this the right way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable is empty because you have a typo. You initialize `$titleentencoded` but later use `$titleencoded`:

```
<?php $titleentencoded = urlencode($titleent); ?>

// Should be
<?php $titleencoded = urlencode($titleent); ?>
```

See @Quentin's answer for a logic error.

Comment: Typos...the bane of every programmer's existence.

Comment: Thanks... And yes, typos, hate them with the power of a 1000 suns. Sucks my brain's responsible for them ;)

Comment: Use JS, Python, Java or any modern language, and it will at least warn you and not silently fail :)

Answer (score 4):

You are doing it backwards.

You are putting data in a URL, then a URL in an HTML document.

You need to urlencode the data, put it in the URL **then** htmlencode the URL and put it in the document.